# Creating table with IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython, python, disassemblers

I'd like to create the table like below, I could not found any clue while googling it.
Is it possible to make table with `IDAPython`, especially with `idaapi.simplecustviewer_t` class?

[image]

Any advises would be helpful for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

These table/list views are called “choosers” in IDA, so look for that keyword in the samples.